# Create javascript object with string type key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create an object some thing like this

```
var key = "key";
var obj={};
obj[key] = "value";
```

My required output is

```
{ "key":"valie"}
```

Key type must be string because i have keys like #12:5 , #12:89 ( orientDB  ids ). 
REASON:-
Because embeddedList of orientDB is not accepting any key without quotes.
Thanks

Comment: Will there be nested objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for JSON syntax.

Here's output from my console.

```
var key = "key"; //var not Var
var obj={}; //same here
obj[key] = "value";
"value"
obj
Object {key: "value"} //key is not in quotes, need to stringify!
JSON.stringify(obj);
"{"key":"value"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Object literals in javascript can be declared with quoted keys:

```
{
  "Okeli-dokeli": "Flanders",
  "Doh!": "Simpson!"
}
```

You can also dynamically assign values to a key in javascript with the bracket syntax:

```
var x = {};
x["A B C"] = "foo";
```

#### ADDED:

The JSON format is based on a subset of javascript but has object keys which are always quoted. Therefore converting any javascript object to JSON will "stringify" the keys:

```
> JSON.stringify( { a : 'b' } )
> "{"a":"b"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance you are not expecting nested objects, this can easily work as well:

```
var key = "key";
var obj={};
obj[key] = "value";


var s = "{\r\n";
for (var p in obj) s+= '    "'+p+'": "' + obj[p] + '"\r\n';
s += "}\r\n";
```

Also, it's `var`, not `Var` (no capital first letter).